# Make a JSON Query to retrieve most relavent result in ElasticSearch

Tags: json, rest, lucene, elasticsearch

I have this Mapping

```
{
  "users":
  {
    "_all" : {"enabled" : false},
    "properties":
    {
        "user": 
        {
           "type":"multi_field",
           "fields":
           {
              "user":{"type":"string"},
              "original":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}
           }
        }
        "school":{"type":"string","index": "not_analyzed"},
        "college":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},
        "uni":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}
    }
  }
}
```

With Such data

```
{
  "user": "Abdul Jabbar",
  "school": "Aisha Bawany Academy",
  "college": "Pakistan Air Force",
  "uni": "Aptech Computer Education"
}

{
  "user": "Abdul Jabbar WebBestow",
  "school": "Sadaya Academy",
  "college": "Pakistan Air Force",
  "uni": "WebBestow"
}

{
  "user":"Abdul Jabbar Leopard",
  "school":"Innocent Public School",
  "college":"Lucene College of Science",
  "uni":"IBM"
}

{
  "user":"Abdul Jabbar Loharwada",
  "school":"Aisha Bawany Academy",
  "college":"Behria College",
  "uni":"Karachi University"
}

{
  "user":"Abdul Raheem Loharwada",
  "school":"Aisha Bawany Academy",
  "college":"Indus College",
  "uni":"Preston University"
}
```

I want to get all users with user containing word "Jabb" and those results should be on top which have *"Aisha Bawany Academy" or "Pakistan Air Force" or "Aptech Computer Education"* in their any of school, college or uni fields and those documents which contain word "Jabb" but no related data in their school, college or uni fields should be below top results.

Even though the user complete name is "Abdul Jabbar *" and so on but when we type only "Jabb" it should bring above documents with any user containing word "Jabb".

How can i make such a JSON query? Please help us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your new mapping and data, the following query returns results for me.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "prefix": {
                  "user": "jabb"
               }
            }
         ],
         "should": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "school": {
                      "query": "Aisha Bawany Academy"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "college": {
                      "query": "Aisha Bawany Academy"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "uni": {
                      "query": "Aisha Bawany Academy"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}'
```

The problem might be that you changed "College" to "college" and so on, so the query has to be updated as well. In general, ES is case-sensitive.

Also notice that the query "jabb" is lower-case in my example. This is necessary since the prefix query does not do any analysis on the query text, and the "user" field has been analyzed with the standard analyzer (since no analyzer is specified in the mapping) which modifies tokens to lower-case. Even though some the documents indexed have the text "Jabbar", this will be tokenized to "jabbar", and so the prefix query "Jabb" doesn't match any tokens.

You can read about the prefix query here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html

and the standard analyzer here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html

Also, since you are wanting to match several values to several fields, the following query structure might work better:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "prefix": {
                  "user": "jabb"
               }
            }
         ],
         "should": [
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Aisha Bawany Academy",
                  "fields": ["school", "college", "uni"]
               }
            },
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Pakistan Air Force",
                  "fields": ["school", "college", "uni"]
               }
            },
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Aptech Computer Education",
                  "fields": ["school", "college", "uni"]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply Sloan. But I don't know why your current query is still not resulting anything. What can be the reason? is my current mapping creating problem?

Comment: We are feeling trapped here please help us.

Comment: It's hard to say. I'll post what I did step-by-step, and maybe that will help you figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Yahooo!!!!!!! Thanks Sloan. Thankssssssssss Alot Man. Love You. I Love You Man. It worked great.

Comment: Actually my team mate had made few changes in Mappings so i backed them and it worked.

Comment: Might I could give you some party.

Answer (score 1):

I created an index with default mappings using the four documents you provided. The following query seems to accomplish what you want:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "prefix": {
                  "user": "john"
               }
            }
         ],
         "should": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "School": {
                      "query": "DDD"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "College": {
                      "query": "BBB"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}'
```

yielding the result:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 2,
      "successful": 2,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0.6043929,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "docs",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.6043929,
            "_source": {
               "user": "Johnathan",
               "School": "DDD",
               "College": "AAA"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "docs",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.43922842,
            "_source": {
               "user": "John Doe",
               "School": "AAA",
               "College": "BBB"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "docs",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 0.15109822,
            "_source": {
               "user": "Johnson",
               "School": "AAA",
               "College": "EEE"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Notice that the prefix query is in a "must" clause, so only results matching that query will be returned, and the other two requirements are in a "should" clause, so that matching results will be ranked higher. You can further customize the scoring by adding "boost" values to the match queries if needed, though "match" combined with "bool" does a decent job using default ES behavior.

As far as the second question, a default installation of elasticsearch available over http is definitely vulnerable to tampering. There are a number of ways to handle the problem. You can install an authentication plugin and/or a reverse proxy like nginx to handle authentication, so that only users who are logged in can access Elasticsearch. You can also use white-listed IPs so that only trusted IPs are able to access ES. We offer both of these methods at [Qbox](http://qbox.io), but both are a little problematic for use with a javascript application. A method we have found that works well for client-side applications is to require authentication by default for all ES access, but to create a "search-only" endpoint in the nginx conf that allows any unauthenticated users to search, but not edit data. In that case you probably also want to disable scripting in the ES conf. If none of these approaches will work, then you probably want to close ES off to http traffic and build your own application wrapper around it so that you can secure it in any way you need to.

Comment: Great Sloan Ahrens! Thanks alot man. You are just awesome. And can you  give me an example of boost you said please with above example. We really need this to be completed. You can't imagine how much that query is important to us. I will let my friends working on it. Please give us boost example if possible for you. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Sloan Ahrens. Though we have this question last night but every 5 mins till then i visited to see if someone has answered. Thanks again. Please Scoring Boost example please.

Answer (score 0):

Adding boosting to the previous example is simple enough. Suppose I want a match on "College" to be boosted more than "School", you could modify the query as follows:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "prefix": {
                  "user": "john"
               }
            }
         ],
         "should": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "School": {
                      "query": "DDD",
                      "boost":1
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "College": {
                      "query": "BBB",
                      "boost":2
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}'
```

and then the result set looks like:

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 2,
      "successful": 2,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0.49520478,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "docs",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.49520478,
            "_source": {
               "user": "John Doe",
               "School": "AAA",
               "College": "BBB"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "docs",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.36333188,
            "_source": {
               "user": "Johnathan",
               "School": "DDD",
               "College": "AAA"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "docs",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 0.09083297,
            "_source": {
               "user": "Johnson",
               "School": "AAA",
               "College": "EEE"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

You might have to tune the numbers a little to get exactly what you want. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Ok let me go through this Sloan. I will let you know. Thanks for your such nice support. Thanks alot.

Comment: the bool query you said is not working and giving null result. We have changed few mappings and data. It's not working now. I am providing my query and mapping with data in question. Please check if possible.

Comment: We are missing you @Sloan Ahrens, Please Help us out.

Comment: We have updated our question with latest data, please check @Sloan Alrens

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if seeing all my steps helps you figure out what's going wrong.

First delete the index if it exists, to start over:

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/test_index"
```

Then create it:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/"
```

Then create the mapping for "users":

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/users/_mapping" -d'
{
  "users":
  {
    "_all" : {"enabled" : false},
    "properties":
    {
        "user": 
        {
           "type":"multi_field",
           "fields":
           {
              "user":{"type":"string"},
              "original":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}
           }
        },
        "school":{"type":"string","index": "not_analyzed"},
        "college":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},
        "uni":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}
    }
  }
}'
```

and check to make sure it worked:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test_index/users/_mapping"
...
{
   "users": {
      "_all": {
         "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
         "college": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "omit_norms": true,
            "index_options": "docs"
         },
         "school": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "omit_norms": true,
            "index_options": "docs"
         },
         "uni": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "omit_norms": true,
            "index_options": "docs"
         },
         "user": {
            "type": "multi_field",
            "fields": {
               "user": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "original": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "omit_norms": true,
                  "index_options": "docs",
                  "include_in_all": false
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then add the docs:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/users/1" -d'
{
  "user": "Abdul Jabbar",
  "school": "Aisha Bawany Academy",
  "college": "Pakistan Air Force",
  "uni": "Aptech Computer Education"
}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/users/2" -d'
{
  "user": "Abdul Jabbar WebBestow",
  "school": "Sadaya Academy",
  "college": "Pakistan Air Force",
  "uni": "WebBestow"
}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/users/3" -d'
{
  "user":"Abdul Jabbar Leopard",
  "school":"Innocent Public School",
  "college":"Lucene College of Science",
  "uni":"IBM"
}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/users/4" -d'
{
  "user":"Abdul Jabbar Loharwada",
  "school":"Aisha Bawany Academy",
  "college":"Behria College",
  "uni":"Karachi University"
}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/users/5" -d'
{
  "user":"Abdul Raheem Loharwada",
  "school":"Aisha Bawany Academy",
  "college":"Indus College",
  "uni":"Preston University"
}'
```

The run the query:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "prefix": {
                  "user": "jabb"
               }
            }
         ],
         "should": [
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Aisha Bawany Academy",
                  "fields": ["school", "college", "uni"]
               }
            },
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Pakistan Air Force",
                  "fields": ["school", "college", "uni"]
               }
            },
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Aptech Computer Education",
                  "fields": ["school", "college", "uni"]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}'
```

and the result is:

```
{
   "took": 27,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 2,
      "successful": 2,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
      "max_score": 1.5784466,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.5784466,
            "_source": {
               "user": "Abdul Jabbar",
               "school": "Aisha Bawany Academy",
               "college": "Pakistan Air Force",
               "uni": "Aptech Computer Education"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.32274455,
            "_source": {
               "user": "Abdul Jabbar WebBestow",
               "school": "Sadaya Academy",
               "college": "Pakistan Air Force",
               "uni": "WebBestow"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 0.32274455,
            "_source": {
               "user": "Abdul Jabbar Loharwada",
               "school": "Aisha Bawany Academy",
               "college": "Behria College",
               "uni": "Karachi University"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.06631388,
            "_source": {
               "user": "Abdul Jabbar Leopard",
               "school": "Innocent Public School",
               "college": "Lucene College of Science",
               "uni": "IBM"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```

}

Comment: Sloan please modify query that what if we need to prefix on 2 fields? We are totally dumb at DSL Query and need to complete project at all. So, that's why disturbing you. But this is last question.

Comment: I think you could just add another prefix query to the "must" clause.

Comment: Whatever man. You are just awesome. Thanks for your such kind support.

Comment: Ok Great. Thanks Sloan. Thanks Alot. May You and Your Stacksearch live long long longgggggggggggggg. Amin. Thanks Alot.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Please come see us at http://qbox.io if you need hosted Elasticsearch! :)

Comment: Yup! i visited it and discussed it with my team mates. Will must contact you when we get enough grip over elasticsearch. We will surely urge our Clients to look forward at your hosting.